# How do I write to a file on both Windows and Android in a Java library?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Problem:
How do I write to a file in the Downloads folder on both Android and Windows in my Java library?

**Summary:**
I want to write to a file in the Downloads folder of either Windows or Android with a Java library I'm using in both IntelliJ for a Windows desktop application, and Android Studio in an Android application.

Here is how I'm acquiring the file path in the Windows desktop application:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` on Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare How would I get the path to both of them at the same time? I can't access Android API's from inside a Java library.

Comment: I would write two libraries. You're welcome to try to play some reflection games to see if `android.os.Environment` exists and call the method that way.

Comment: Windows having a Downloads folder? Never heard of that. Never seen one.

Comment: @greenapps You've never seen C:\Users\<username>\Downloads?

Comment: No. Not that i know of. And when would i have used that?

Comment: The Downloads folder was mostly just an example. I need to write to a file in both Windows and Android from within the same Java library.